# Custom UIButton/Image Picker memory woes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In the iOS app I'm writing, we have an "add photo" button that's pretty common--when pressed the user is presented with an action sheet to either take or pick a photo, goes to either the camera or photo library, and then is returned back to the controller. After choosing the image, it's resized and set as the background of the original button that was tapped.

To help clean things up, I decided to put a lot of this functionality inside a custom button, `AddPhotoButton`. When the button is tapped, instead of the controller handling the action sheet and image picker, `AddPhotoButton` itself does. This works pretty well in some case, but in others I'm running into a lot of memory issues. When the camera pops up, the controller containing the button ends up releasing it, and so when UIImagePickerController tries to call the delegate method (`AddPhotoButton` is its delegate), the object no longer exists, because nothing owns it.

So, what I'm really asking is--what's the best way to deal with something like this? I'd like to have the photo button functionality (show the action sheet, image picker, and then set the background image) all bundled up together, so it's easy to reuse, but it seems like the approach I took was incorrect. However, maybe I am doing it correctly, but should be retaining the button a different way.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to do this is generally avoiding because you are unnecessarily tying the interface to the background logic by storing logic in a subclass of a GUI element. However, nothing you are doing is technically wrong and it sounds like it should work, you are just handling memory management wrong. So I will offer two possible solutions:

**Fix memory management**
To tell you how to fix that I would have to see some code. Why is the old view controller releasing the button? Are you transiting away from the view controller or are you adding the other one on top?

**Improve Class Design**(preferred)
Instead of adding your logic to a button subclass, you could create a controller class. This is not a view or any gui element at all. Let's call it "ButtonBackgroundPicker". This class will have a method that says to start choosing an image that also takes the button to change the background of as an argument. The ButtonBackgroundPicker would handle all of the logic and when done, it would set the background of the button. All the button should do is create the ButtonBackgroundPicker and call the function to pick an image giving it a reference to itself. If you want to be able to pick a background for other types of UI elements you could create a protocol within ButtonBackgroundPicker that the element needs to implement so that the ButtonBackgroundPicker can report choosing an image. Then instead of passing the element in with the function, you would set it as a delegate of the controller.

The reason this design is preferred is that it doesn't couple the gui and logic together. You could easily extend this design to work with other UIElements. Using a delegate is even better because you can use the same class and code for pretty much anything you want to do with regards to picking an image.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up just fixing the memory management aspect--I was releasing the button on viewDidUnload, which was causing issues. I do like the second option, as then I could release the UI elements in viewDidUnload and only retain the Picker, so I'll probably switch to that when I have a chance.